# Yii Ajax on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have some app on Yii. I want to implement ajax calls on click of div.
I've found some [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/388/ajax-form-submiting-in-yii/) with form ajax validation, but it'snot clear for me, how can I do what I want. That's what I did:

```
$(document).on('click','div.lessonDiv', function()
    {
       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../protected/controllers/AjaxController.php",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
}
```

That says that the directory is forbidden. Where should I put file which is able to interact with ajax? Or it alreay has it? 
**UPDATE** I'm using version 1.1.

Comment: When asking anout Yii, clarify which version do you use - 1 or 2. It is important, version 1.1 is still widely used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call files directly, Yii doesn't work this way. It is MVC framework with controllers and actions and it uses routes, also for AJAX request. So you should add an **action** to `AjaxController` and call `createUrl` to get it's URL.

**PHP**

```
class AjaxController extends CController
{
    public funcion actionDoThing()
    {
        // Get request object
        $request = Yii::app()->request;

        // Check if request is acceptable
        if ($request->isPost && $request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            echo CJSON::encode(array('hello'=>'world'));
        }
        // else
        // {
        //     throw new CHttpException(403);
        // }
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','div.lessonDiv', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <?php echo $this->createUrl('ajax/doThing'); ?>,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I'd recommend to read [Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en) more closely. It is also available in [Russian](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru)

Comment: And where should I put AjaxController?

Comment: @SergeyScopin in `protected/controllers/AjaxController.php`. It's very basic stuff, RTFM

Comment: I know where I should put all the controllers. I suggested that there is some special place for ajax may be. Thanx for your help.

Comment: @SergeyScopin Ok, sorry for tediousness :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on('click','div.lessonDiv', function()
    {
       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Ajax/index'); ?>",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
    });
```

To learn about **createUrl()** in YII click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createUrl-de)